# LightSwitch application without UI layer

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

Is it possible to have a Lightswitch application serve as a data service layer only? Can I create a Lightswitch application without a UI layer and use it as a data service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely! That's one of the coolest things about Lightswitch.
See [OData Apps In Lightswitch](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmattsampson/archive/2012/03/19/odata-apps-in-lightswitch.aspx) (there is also a part II), and this [How-To Video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/jj614424)

When you go to `Publish` a Lightswitch app, one of the options under "Application Type" is "*Service Only*".